# Is it possible to have a failed Bitcoin transaction on the block chain?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind

In Ethereum, a transaction may get out of gas but still being included in a block with a receipt status of failed. In Bitcion, will similar things happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Invalid transactions do not get included in blocks in Bitcoin.

There is also no `receipt` concept in Bitcoin. All nodes run full verification and check transactions against their own UTXO set when importing a block. Therefore any invalid transaction will also cause a block to be invalid as well.